# Правильное переопределение значений свойств max-width и min-width

Tags: css, media-queries

Есть **три медиа выражения** для трех типов экранов устройств (мобильного, планшетного, и дескотпного). На мобильном разрешении я хочу **ограничить минимальную и максимальную ширину** при которых стили для мобильных устройств будут срабатывать.

```
.container {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 480px;
}
```

Таким образом сайт на мобильных устройствах различных габаритов будет отображаться на всю ширину экрана устройства, размеры которых разнятся **от 320px до 480px.** Выше **480px** сайт будет оставаться в фиксированном разрешении (480px) расположенным центру.

```
.container {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Затем на планшетной версии, разрешение экрана составит **768px**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 740px; 
  } 
}
```

Но вот не задача то, сверху наследуются правила `min-width` и `max-width` которые для планшета совершено не нужны. Если `min-width` никакого влияния не оказывает, то `max-width` сжимает сайт до своего значения **480px**.

Можно решить эту задачу просто дав **max** и **min-width** одинаковые значения необходимой ширины

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 740px;
    min-width: 740px;
    max-width: 740px;
  } 
}
```

В таком случае значения свойств переопределяться, но это выглядит не очень правильно как по мне. Есть ли другое решение, более эстетичное?

Comment: Как вы всё усложняете. Просто оставьте ширину контейнера 100% и `margin:0 auto`, а на необходимых разрешениях медиазапросами устанавливайте `max-width`

Comment: Сделал согласно вашей рекомендации и прикрепил код к теме, но как мне теперь ограничить ширину контейнера до 320px, чтобы ниже этого разрешения появлялся скролл

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров А всё, допёр самостоятельно и изменил код в посте. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: отлично! Оформите ответ на свой вопрос, может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Назначаем контейнеру `width: 100%`

```
.container {
  outline: 1px solid #000000; /* Для наглядности */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; }
```

Чтобы ограничить область в пределах которой будут отображаться стили для мобильных устройств устанавливаем:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .container {
    min-width: 320px; } }

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .container  {
    max-width: 480px; } }
```

Таким образом при разрешении ниже **320px** контейнер не будет ужиматься, а выше **480px** не будет расширяться, а останется зафиксированным по центру благодаря `margin: 0 auto`

Ну и теперь просто переопределяем значение свойства `max-width` устанавливая нужный нам размер контейнера, для соответствующих разрешений экрана.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 748px; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1180px; } }
```

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; }

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .container {
    min-width: 320px; } }

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .container  {
    max-width: 480px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 748px; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1180px; } }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Контент
</div>
```